# How to fetch all data from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch all data from mysql database but i wonder why it is not working did i missed something here?
This is the code:

```
 $tid=$_SESSION['id'];
 $a=mysql_query("select * from tbl_curriculum_sched where TEACHER_ID='$tid'");          

 while($ad=mysql_fetch_array($a)){
     $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * from enrolled where CURRICULUM_SCHED_ID='$ad[0]'");
     //the value of  $ad[0] returns nothing
     //i did something here
     //but it is not working
 }
```

what's wrong with this query?

Comment: What means "not working" *exactly*?

Comment: Dont use `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated and also a horrid, horrid interface. Use [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`Mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). Now that that is out of the way... Are you sure there is a value in `$_SESSION['id']`? Did you call `session_start()` before trying to use it? I also dont see where you called `mysql_connect()` or `mysql_select_db()` - did you also call those?

Comment: What does `mysql_error()` say is wrong with your query?

Comment: @melly: WRT your updated code... you can fetch all this data in a single query with a join like `SELECT c.*, e.* FROM tbl_curriculum_sched c LEFT JOIN enrolled s ON (c.id = e.CURRICULUM_SCHED_ID) WHERE c.TEACHER_ID = ?` the `?` representing where you would put `$tid`. (Note: I may have your columns wrong since i dont know you schema but thats the general idea).

Comment: @Alejandro i updated the question $ad[0] has no value. my session has the value (id)

Comment: @prodigitalson i did call the `mysql_connect` and the `mysql_select_db`

Comment: @melly What about the `session_start()`?

Comment: i have `session_start()` i did this `echo "select * from tbl_curriculum_sched where TEACHER_ID='$tid'";` and `$tid` has the value of 1 but when i `echo` this line after the `while`, `echo "SELECT * from enrolled where CURRICULUM_SCHED_ID='$ad[0]'"` the `$ad[0]` returns null/nothing

Comment: this is really strange! i put $ad=mysql_fetch_array($a) outside the while loop and i used var_dump($ad) then run, it returns lots of values as an array. but when i put it back to the while loop it is null. what is happening? what is wrong with this?!!!! this is working awhile ago!! why is it like this now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DO NOT USE MYSQL, instead use MySQLi as MySQL is *DEPRECATED* .

But:

```
$tid=$_SESSION['id'];
 $a=mysql_query("select * from tbl_curriculum_sched where TEACHER_ID='$tid'") or die("$ a error : ".mysql_error());          

 while($ad=mysql_fetch_array($a)){
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * from enrolled where CURRICULUM_SCHED_ID='$ad[0]'") or die("inner while: ".mysqli_error());
...
```

To those of you commenting and comlaining that the OP should  be using $a, rather than `$ad` - no, this is not the case - as the `while` statement will output content into the `$ad` variable as both named and numerical keys.

Also: The database connection needs to be declared.

Also: `session_start()` needs to be declared.

If the `$ad[0]` specifically does not have a value and no `mysql_error()` has been thrown then look into using `mysql_fetch_row` as settings in PHP ini mean that possibly the numerical keying of data from the MySQL table is not kept, and data is possibly only stored by name, which is better way to use the data all round.

Try and avoid using `SELECT *` too.

Comment: this is really strange! i put `$ad=mysql_fetch_array($a)` outside the while loop and i used `var_dump($ad)` then run, it returns lots of values as an array. but when i put it back to the while loop it is null. what is happening? what is wrong with this?!!!! this is working awhile ago!! why is it like this now..

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this helped me when i had strange problem with var with index in sql:

```
$var_temp = $ad[0];
```

In The sql Query put:

```
'$var_temp'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try var dump maybe you can see something to debug

```
while($ad=mysql_fetch_array($a)){
 $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * from enrolled where CURRICULUM_SCHED_ID='$ad[0]'");
   var_dump($sql);
}
```